# Has anyone implemented the PayPal PHP SDK with an openssl certificate?

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I read the documentation about security and concerns, but I can see any example with how use a .pem file to autenticate to PayPal API V2, the classic version has this feature. I want to send payments but using this method.

Has anyone share some code to see?

this is my code

```
  require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';


  class PaymentPayPal
  {
      public static function SendPayment($member)
     {
       $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                'ClientID','ClientSecret'
            )
        );


        $apiContext->setConfig(
        array(
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        )
        );

       $payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();

        $senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
        $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
            ->setEmailSubject("You have a payment");

        $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader);

                $senderItem1 = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
                $senderItem1->setRecipientType('Email')
                    ->setNote('Thanks you.')
                    ->setReceiver($member['email'])
                    ->setSenderItemId(uniqid())
                    ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                                        "value":"'.$member['amount'].'",
                                        "currency":"USD"
                                    }'));
                $payouts->addItem($senderItem1);

     try {

             $output = $payouts->create(null, $apiContext);
              var_dump($output);

              $status = \PayPal\Api\Payout::get($output->batch_header->payout_batch_id, $apiContext);
              var_dump($status);

            } catch (Exception $ex) {

          }


      }

 }
```